# vuex unknown local mutation type: updateValue, global type: app/updateValue. Mutations don't work

Tags: vue.js, action, vuex, store, mutation

I want to apply mutations through actions to a variable in my vuejs application. But I get this error saying `[vuex] unknown local mutation type: updateValue, global type: app/updateValue`

Here is my **store** folder structure:

```
-store
    -modules
    -app
        -actions.js
        -getters.js
        -mutations.js
        -state.js
    -index.js
    -actions.js
    -getters.js
    -mutations.js
    -state.js
    -index.js
```

This is my **./store/index.js** file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

import actions from './actions'
import getters from './getters'
import modules from './modules'
import mutations from './mutations'
import state from './state'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    actions,
    getters,
    modules,
    mutations,
    state
})

export default store
```

This is my **./store/modules/index.js**:

```js
const requireModule = require.context('.', true, /\.js$/)
const modules = {}

requireModule.keys().forEach(fileName => {
    if (fileName === './index.js') return

    // Replace ./ and .js
    const path = fileName.replace(/(\.\/|\.js)/g, '')
    const [moduleName, imported] = path.split('/')

        if (!modules[moduleName]) {
            modules[moduleName] = {
            namespaced: true
        }
    }

    modules[moduleName][imported] = requireModule(fileName).default
})

export default modules
```

This is my **./store/modules/app/actions.js**:

```js
export const updateValue = ({commit}, payload) => {
    commit('updateValue', payload)
}
```

This is my **./store/modules/app/getters.js**:

```js
export const value = state => {
    return state.wruValue;
}
```

This is my **./store/modules/app/mutations.js**:

```js
import { set, toggle } from '@/utils/vuex'

export default {
    setDrawer: set('drawer'),
    setImage: set('image'),
    setColor: set('color'),
    toggleDrawer: toggle('drawer')
}

export const updateValue = (state, payload) => {
    state.wruValue = payload * 12;
}
```

This is my **./store/modules/app/state.js**:

```js
export default {
    drawer: null,
    color: 'green',
    wruValues:1,
    wruValue: 1,
}
```

and finally this is my vue component:

```
<v-btn @click="updateValue(10)">
    SHOW
</v-btn>

import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
...mapActions ('app',[
                'updateValue'
            ]),
```

So when I click on the button I expect to see the `wruValue` to change (I print the value somewhere else for testing purposes) but instead I get the error mentioned above. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't believe you can namespace the topmost store:
`const store = new Vuex.Store({    namespaced: true, //... etc` (in your ./store/index.js file). The `namespace` property is reserved for modules only.

Answer (score 15):

```
commit('updateValue', payload, {root: true})
```

But I find your use of namespacing odd. For my projects, I don't separate out files for getters, actions, etc, I separate out tasks, projects, companies, etc. But if it works for you, that's fine. It doesn't seem like the issue. If you still get an error, you might need to change "updateValue" to "mutations/updateValue" or something.

Answer (score -1):

You should use this project structure:

[image]

**src/store/modules/app.js**

```js
export const state = {
  drawer: null,
  color: 'green',
  wruValues: 1,
  wruValue: 1
}

export const mutations = {
  UPDATE_VALUE: (state, payload) => {
    state.wruValue = payload * 12
  }
}

export const actions = {
  updateValue: ({ commit }, payload) => {
    commit('UPDATE_VALUE', payload)
  }
}

export const getters = {
  getWruValue: (state) => state.wruValue
}
```

**src/store/index.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const requireContext = require.context('./modules', true, /.*\.js$/)

const modules = requireContext.keys()
  .map(file =>
    [file.replace(/(^.\/)|(\.js$)/g, ''), requireContext(file)]
  )
  .reduce((modules, [name, module]) => {
    if (module.namespaced === undefined) {
      module.namespaced = true
    }

    return { ...modules, [name]: module }
  }, {})

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules
})
```

**src/main.js**

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

**src/App.vue**

```vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="updateValue(10)">
      SHOW
    </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('app', ['updateValue'])
  }
}
</script>
```

Then if you want to add a new store namespace, u need to put it inside of src/modules folder.

Comment: It is inside of methods. forgot to copy it here